# In SwiftUI, is there a single @State for all windows?

Tags: swiftui

I have a very simple View as follows:

```swift
struct S {
  private let id = UUID()
  var i: Int = 0
  init() { print("creating a new S: \(id)") }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var s = S()
  static let colors = [Color.yellow, .teal, .brown, .mint, .blue, .red]
  init() { print("creating a new content view") }
  
  var body: some View {
     Text("\(s.i): Hello")
    .onAppear {
      s.i = Int.random(in: 0..<ContentView.colors.count)
      print("assigned \(ContentView.colors[s.i])")
    }
    .padding()
    .background(ContentView.colors[s.i])
  }
}
```

and I expected that there would be a new `@State` for each new window.  But that doesn't seem to be the case, if I create a few windows I see this in the output:

```
creating a new S: AD34D628-29F8-407F-8F7E-FA2EC23A00E7
creating a new content view
assigned teal
assigned brown
assigned mint
assigned mint
```

Also, each window displays its color index (see pic).

So there appears to be multiple instances of the state, each with its own index, but according to the output only one instance was constructed.

Can someone explain what's going on here and how does this work?  Does SwiftUI create a single instance of every and any `@State`, period, or can there be many states under different circumstances?

If always one instance but it can *split* like this so each window gets its version, is this behavior one can always count on?

And finally, does anyone know of a place where this is described in detail?  The Apple Developer documentation seems to be pretty terse and I haven't been able to find any in-depth discussion about how this works.

[image]

Comment: How are you creating the new windows?

Comment: @jnpdx I am creating the new windows by pressing Cmd+N (this in macOS).  I've got the minimal default app: `struct Foo : App { var body: some Scene { WindowGroup { ContentView() } } }`

Comment: AppStorage is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this behavior one can always count on?

Yes, in the sense that each window has its own independent state. As the documentation for [`WindowGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup) says:

> Every window in the group maintains independent state. For example, the system allocates new storage for any State or StateObject variables instantiated by the scene’s view hierarchy for each window that it creates.

You seem to be assuming that `init` needs to be called to create a new state. This is not true for value types like your `S`. They use value-semantics. You can create a new, independent instance just by passing them to a function, or assigning them to a new variable.

```
var a = S()
var b = a
// now a and b are two independent values - init() is only called once
// this doesn’t change a:
b.i = 10
```

The same applies to your `ContentView` too. This is why you should not expect your view's `init` to be called a certain number of times. SwiftUI can call it once, even if there are many of that same view showing on the screen, and it can call it many times, even if there is only one `ContentView` on the screen. This is all implementation detail.

If I had to guess, SwiftUI likely called `ContentView.init` once, and made copies of `ContentView` (without calling `init` anymore), hence indirectly copying all the `@State`s.

---

On the other hand, The `init` of *reference types* must be called, for multiple independent objects to be created. If you make `S` a class and use `@StateObject` instead of `@State`, you'd see "creating a new S" multiple times.

```
class S: ObservableObject {
    private let id = UUID()
    @Published var i: Int = 0
    init() { print("creating a new S: \(id)") }
}

...

@StateObject private var s = S()
```

Comment: Thanks.  So in Swift copying value types is just a memcpy or something like that?   If I had written an initializer like `struct S {  init(_ s: S) { ...} }` would that have gotten used by the compiler or no?
Also, how does one control the `@State` of the new `ContentView`?  Can't do it in the state or view's initializers, since they are not guaranteed to be called, so is there a different standard pattern here?  Perhaps in `.onAppear` or something like that?
Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: @giik I’m not sure of the implementation details. For small struct it might just be a mov instruction. You can read more about this if you just look up “swift value types vs reference types”. No your “copy initialiser” will not be called, and yes you can use `onAppear` if you need to do something when the view appears.

Comment: @giik You can also try using a `@StateObject` to see how reference types behave. See the edit.